# Ir para uma nova view com JSon

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo um exclusão com Ajax e retornando um JSon. **Como eu faço para abrir uma view diferente?**
Segue o código, coloquei o url mais não funciona:

View

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ExcluirPedidoCompra")', // to get the right path to controller from TableRoutes of Asp.Net MVC
    dataType: "json", //to work with json format
    type: "POST", //to do a post request
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
    cache: false, //avoid caching results
    data: "{\"id\" : " + id + "}", // here you can pass arguments to your request if you need
    success: function (data) {

        if (data > 0) {
           url: '/PedidoCompraConsultar/Index'
        }

    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("Erro! Ocorreu um erro ao excluir, Favor Entrar em Contato com O Suporte.");
    }
});
```

código do controller

```
public ActionResult ExcluirPedidoCompra(int id)
{
    var resultado = 1;
    return Json(resultado);
}
```

Já testei de todas as forma. Se alguém puder me ajudar quero ir para "PedidoCompraConsultarController - Index".

Comment: testou,  url: '@Url.Action("PedidoCompraConsultar")'  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca dessa forma :

```
window.location.href= 'rota'
```

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo